# How to create a fixed width image style for all landscape and portrait images?

Tags: media

I have an image style: Scale 580x580px.

- When I upload a *landscape* image it gets a width of 580px.
- When I upload e.g a *portrait* image with **809 (width) x 1100px (height)** the width of the image (after image style is applied) on the page is **427 x 580px.**

How do I manage the width is always 580px? So for all uploaded landscape and portrait images?

Comment: I believe you need to use "Scale and Crop"

Comment: @No Sssweat but don't you think with Scale and Crop it cut's the image to exactly 580 x 580px? If I upload an image which is 600px x 900px the image style should make the image **580px x 870px**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Scale` only scales the image so it looks proportionate. It will go with either the height 580px or width 580px, which ever is closer.

If you want your image to be exactly 580px *x* 580px you could use `Resize` but you will see your image will look stretched.

The only other option that will give you the exact 580px *x* 580px is `Scale and Crop`

If you are afraid that something important will get cut off, you can use this awesome module:

**[Focal Point](https://www.drupal.org/project/focal_point)** by DA's own [bleen](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/63043/bleen)

> Focal Point allows you to specify the portion of an image that is most
>   important. This information can be used when the image is cropped or
>   cropped and scaled so that you don't, for example, end up with an
>   image that cuts off the subject's head.

Then use `Focal Point Scale and Crop` as your image style effect.